# Populate data in the application with out sign up android

Tags: android

I am developing a news application. I dont want users to register in the application. When users download the application, data should be populated in the app from the server and any data added should be updated in the application.

How to update the data when any news has been added i.e how to identify users and send the data?

Answer (score 0):

Your server don't need to track the new user. It is your app which will tell the server about the user. Write your data fetching code on the very first screen of your application (say Splash screen) and do check if there is any update on the server end

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of fetching data on your Splash Screen, but if you dont want your user to get stuck you can use Intent Services to fetch your data in background, Once your data is received from server you can show it to the user.
 [How to use IntentService](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android)